# React Native - Expo publishing issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have this project I have built locally using React native + Expo.  I published it, and it said it was successfully published.  However in the "builds" area in expo.io, it says "You currently have no builds."

[image: My terminal showing expo-cli]
[image: My expo.io account]

What am I doing wrong here?  How do I get my simple test app to show up on App store?

Answer (score 0):

"Publishing" a project on Expo just makes that project accessible to other expo clients and other users. You can share the URL of your project and other people can try it out in the Expo Go app or in a browser if supported. If you are trying to distribute your app to an app store, you need to build a standalone app.

Check out the [Expo Guide for building standalone apps](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/).

Side note: if you build a standalone app and distribute it on the app store, you can also publish updates using `expo publish`, and those updates will be downloaded on the standalone apps if [various criteria](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/) are met.